# iOS-Slide-Menu menu does not work when not set as app root controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I have a "loading" root view controller when the app starts which will determine to load either the slide menu controller or another controller, the menu does not work. It is visible, and the animations work just fine, only all touches are disabled.

I've distilled my setup to this:

In the app delegate

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
```

And in the testViewController viewDidAppear:

```
SlideNavigationController *slideNavigationController = [[SlideNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[ARootViewController alloc] init]];
    slideNavigationController.leftMenu = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MenuViewController alloc] init]];
    slideNavigationController.menuRevealAnimator = [[SlideNavigationContorllerAnimatorScaleAndFade alloc] initWithMaximumFadeAlpha:0.6f fadeColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] andMinimumScale:.8];
    slideNavigationController.enableSwipeGesture = NO;
    slideNavigationController.view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;

[self presentViewController:slideNavigationController: animated:YES callback:nil];
```

But then the menu does not respond to touches. If the slide navigation controller is the root view controller in the app delegate the menu does work correctly. It is really a matter of that the slide navigation controller must be the apps root controller. Is there a workaround or fix for this?

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

For others viewing this thread, implement `SlideNavigationControllerDelegate` and add below function in every controller that you do not wish to show side menu icon.
And most importantly it should be the root view controller in app delegate, otherwise it won't work.
Refer to documentation of developer [here](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu).

```
- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayLeftMenu
{
  //or no based on your preference  
  return YES;
}
```